# Redirect to Maintenance Page During Production Database Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, azure, deployment, entity-framework-migrations, swap

I am using Azure websites with staging to warm up changes before swapping to production. However, this solution dies not work with entity framework migrations.

If I enable a migration on the staging slot, then the database is migrated correctly. However, the production website still uses the old migration and is no longer able to connect with the db context and generates an error.

Therefore, the staging website is ok, but production goes down. I have tried to publish directly to production whenever there was a migration with bad results (website going down for 15 minutes as db struggled to migrate while being hit with multiple requests because all caching was reset on the website).

The only solution I can figure out is for the website to go down and to display a maintenance message to users.

What I would like to do is redirect users to a maintenance page that would redirect them back to their previous request after 1 minute with javascript. However, I would only do this for Entity migration errors (db schema change). For other errors, they should go to the standard error page.

I can do this all manually by setting up a maintenance message deployment slot and swapping it to production as I manually deploy the upgrades. However, is there an automated way to do this?

---

### Update: Workaround to take users offline while migrating database

- Upload (with ftp) app_offline.htm to production which displays a simple message to the user and reloads the page every minute with javascript.

  - Deploy Migrations to staging
  - Load staging to execute migrations and warm up web app
  - Swap to production
  - Remove app_offline.htm (now at staging)

Comment: Why would that happen? Are staging and production sharing a database or code?

Comment: Yes, Staging shares the same db. It is only for final warming up the server and final testing before swapping to production. If staging uses it's own db, then the app will reset during a swap in order to use the changed connection strings and the server will not be warmed up, which is the primary purpose of swapping.